# Adding a span within a ruby link_to

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am getting an error with this piece of code. Can anyone see why?

```
<% link_to("#{(current_user.acting_as == "Participant") ? t(:uploaded_by_host) : t(:uploaded_by_you)}", "javascript:void(0)", :class => "button button-mini button-blue") do %>
<span class="icon icon-plus-sign"></span>
<% end %>
```

Error is:

> undefined method `stringify_keys' for "javascript:void(0)":String

Comment: Please, read [API documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org) before asking such questions. Reading docs will help you a lot.

Comment: First error: should be **<%=** instead of **<%** second error: you should set **block** content or **inline** content but not both

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't both pass a block to `link_to` *and* give it link text as an argument. It doesn't make sense either. Amend your code to:

```
<%= link_to("javascript:void(0)", :class => "button button-mini button-blue") do %>
  <span class="icon icon-plus-sign"></span> <%= current_user.acting_as == "Participant" ? t(:uploaded_by_host) : t(:uploaded_by_you) %>
<% end %>
```

See: http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper/link_to (You're using the 4th form here)

Comment: That does not seem to work, it actually does not display the link at all now

Comment: will check out the doc provided, thanks!

Comment: As @Aguardientico said in the comments above, there's an initial `=` missing. I've edited the answer.